# Is there a way to detect 'Aw Snap' pages in Chrome and report to server side?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there a way to detect 'Aw Snap' pages in Chrome and report to server side or a custom location with backtrace ?

Comment: I'm thinking that if you establish a connection with WebSockets, you could find out how the page disconnect.

Answer (score 5):

"Aw Snap" happens when a Chrome process crashes. The page can't find out about that.

It **is** possible to do this in an extension, though. The [onExited event in the experimental processes API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/processes/#event-onExited) provides exitType, which can indicate when a process crashed.